# How to add a <map>-Element to a document using DOM manipulating functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dictionary

I try to add a  to an HTML-Document and link it to an image using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addArea(map, xstart, ystart, xende, yende, idCol, col) {
        area = document.createElement("area");

        area.shape  = "rect";
        area.coords = "" + xstart + ", " + ystart + ", " + xende + ", " + yende + "";
        area.href   = "#" + idCol;
        area.title  = col;
        area.alt    = col;
/*
        area.shape  = "\"rect\"";
        area.coords = "xstart + \", \" + ystart + \", \" + xende + \", \" + yende";
        area.href   = "\"#\" + idCol";
        area.title  = "col";
        area.alt    = "col";

*/      area.setAttribute(
            "onclick",
            "alert(\"Color: \" + col); return false;"
        );

        // append the area to the map
        map.appendChild(area);
    }

    function showMap() {
        idCol = "text";

        // generate the map
        mapCol      = document.createElement("map");
        mapCol.name = "map_" + idCol;
        mapCol.id   = "map_" + idCol;
        addArea(mapCol, 1, 1, 25, 13, idCol, "00FF00");
        addArea(mapCol, 25, 1, 49, 13, idCol, "00FF33");


        imgCol              = document.createElement("img");
        imgCol.src          = "https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
        imgCol.width        = 275;
        imgCol.height       = 95;
        imgCol.style.border = "1px solid #000";
        imgCol.usemap       = "#name_und_raute_sind_notwendig_bunt_" + idCol;
        imgCol.alt          = "Farbe auswählen";

        imgColArea      = document.createElement("p");
        imgColArea.appendChild(imgCol);

        testcol = "ffffff";
        testlink    = document.createElement("a");
        testlink.appendChild(document.createTextNode("testlink"));
        testlink.setAttribute(
            "onclick",
            "alert(\"Color: \" + testcol); return false;"
        );

        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(imgColArea);
        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(testlink);

        alert("map added with " + mapCol.areas.length + " entries.");

    }


    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="showMap()">
<div>
before
<div id="area"></div>
after
</div>
</body>
```

The image should contain linked areas, that alert a text when clicking on them. Unformtunatly the areas do not show up. Does anyone find my mistake?

Comment: `setAttribute('onclick', ...)` is **bad**. You have a DOM element, so you can use proper event handling where you pass a function instead of a code string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your map identifiers mismatch. Also the property name is `useMap`, not `usemap`. Use

```
imgCol.setAttribute('usemap',"#" + mapCol.name);
```

or

```
imgCol.useMap = "#" + mapCol.name;
```

instead. You also have to add your map to the document:

```
/* ... */
imgColArea.appendChild(imgCol);
imgColArea.appendChild(mapCol);
/* ... */
```

[**JSFiddle demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/UFVcA/1/)

Comment: What is the difference between `imgCol.setAttribute('usemap',"#" + mapCol.name);` and `imgCol.usemap = "#" + mapCol.name;`?

Comment: First will work, latter will not ;). (You have to use `imgCol.useMap = '#' + mapCol.name;`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I think you should append your `MAP`-element to the document before assigning children in it. To create new elements differs from creating properties to a non-appended element.